# Ubuntu Mobile SDK on Oneiric

Tags: package-management, 11.10, ppa, ubuntu-sdk

When I try to install Ubuntu Mobile SDK on 11.10, updating repositories gives 404, claiming that libs do not exists in /oneiric/

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa launchpad.net*canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa launchpad.net*canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net*canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad net*ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad net*ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net*ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad net*ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad net*ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad net*ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, 
or old ones used instead.
```

Can the sdk and its components be installed on 11.10 or do I need 12.04 or 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu SDK is only available for Ubuntu 12.04 or later.